# modify circle elements by event listener on text matching id of circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js

first of all sorry for the long title, I couldn't come up with a better one to explain my problem.
What I have is a scatterplot, with `circles` that have different ids based on the `d.FamilyName` column in my csv. Some circles share the same id. 
On the right of that scatterplot, I set up a div, containing a list of all the d.Familyname values, nested to have them show just once. The id of every text is also set by d.FamilyName.
To improve readability of the scatterplot, since it has many values, I was planning to add an `event listener` on mouseover on the text, which should then modify the radius of the circles sharing the same id as the text.

Every circle is plotted inside the `var circle` and the text is plotted inside a div, here's the code for the circle and the text part:

```
var circle = svg.append("g")
                .attr("id", "circles")
                .selectAll("circle")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("circle")
                .attr("cx", function (d) { return x(d.SquadraturaInterna_o); })
                .attr("cy", function (d) { return y(d.SquadraturaEsterna_o); })
                .attr("r", 2)
```

After the radius attribute there's an event listener to show other values of the specified circle (the name and coordinates) but they are not relevant to my problem I think.
The text part:

```
d3.select("#elenco")
.select("#value")
.selectAll("text")
.data(nested)
.enter()
.append("p")
.append("text")
.attr("id", function (i) { return (i).key; })
.text(function (i) { return (i).key; })
.on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
            if (this.id == circle.id) 
            {d3.select("circle")
                .attr("r", 5);
            }
            else {d3.select("circle").attr("r", 1);}

        ;})
.on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
            d3.selectAll("circle")
                .attr("r", 2);
    });
```

The problem is of course on the `if statement` in the `mouseover`.
Any hint on how to solve this would be really appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:** Thanks to @Lars' reply I was able to make this work with a little edit to his code, like so:

```
.on("mouseover", function (d) {
    var sel = this.id;
    circle.filter(function() { return this.id === sel; }).attr("r", 5); })
.on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
            d3.selectAll("circle")
                .attr("r", 2); }
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative to @musically_ut's approach, you can also use the [`.filter()` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-filter) to modify only the elements you want.

```
.on("mouseover", function(d) {
    circle.filter(function() { return this.id === d.FamilyName; }).attr("r", 5);
})
.on("mouseout", function(d) {
    circle.filter(function() { return this.id === d.FamilyName; }).attr("r", 1);
})
```

Comment: Thanks! At first this didn't work, I made it work editing it a little, I'll accept it and add the correct version in my question, just because in the comment it wouldn't be that easy to read

Comment: That was my first impulse too, but I noticed that @tomtomtom wanted to change the radius of _other_ circles to 1 while changing the radius of  the selected one to 5. I thought one `attr` call would be better than 2 `filter` calls.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for this:

```js
    .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
        circles.attr('r', function (circle_d, i) { 
            return (d.id == circle_d.id) ? 5 : 1; 
        });
    })
```

In D3, the `this` in the accessor functions refers to the DOM element. If you wanted to compare the `id` of the DOM element with circle's data's ids, then you could do something like this kind: `d3.select(this).attr('id') == circle_d.id` (cache `d3.select(this).attr('id')` for performance reasons).

Comment: this didn't work unfortunately, and I don't really know what went wrong because the console didn't output any error message